# Unitary operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $U$ be a unitary operator with $\langle Ux,x \rangle\ge 0\quad  \forall x$.

Show that $U$ is the identity operator.

To prove this statement i'm reasoning in this way:

since $U$ is an isometry, $\langle Ux,Uy \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$, i.e. $U^*U=UU^*=I$, with $U^*$ the adjoint of $U$.

I know that $\langle Ux,Ux \rangle =\langle x,x \rangle \ge 0$, but I don't know how to go on.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: $\sigma(U)\subseteq S^1\cap [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Rotation by $90^{0}$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$ is a counter-example, but I think the result is true when the scalar field is $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 3):

False for real scalars but for complex scalars here is a proof: $U$ positive implies $U^{*}=U$  in this case, so $U^{2}=I$. Thus $(U-I)(U+I)=0$. But $U+I$ is invertible so $U-I=0$.

[$\sigma (U) \subseteq [0,\infty)$ since $U$ is positive and $\sigma (U) \subseteq S^{1}$ since $U$ is unitary. Hence, $\sigma (U) \subseteq\{1\}$ which shows that $-1 \notin \sigma (U) $. Hence, $U+I$ is invertible].

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! So a positive unitary operator is self-adjoint?

Comment: Any positive operator is self adjoint when the scalar field is $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why $\sigma(U)\subset\{1\}$. Have you intersected $ [0, \infty)$ with the sphere?

Comment: @giuseppeknecht Yes, the only point in the unit circle which  is positive is $1$.